# How to efficiently separate a large dataset from an HTML page

Tags: html, data-structures

I am attempting to implement a large searchable table of information on a static website- so using SQL or PHP is not possible. I am considering using Datatables, and converting the CSV into HTML. However I feel that having a nearly 3000 long HTML table isn't the most efficient way of doing this? What would be the best way of doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have two files, an HTML page (i.e. the datatable your users will use) and a JSON file where you will store all your data.

Then, use [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to retrieve the data from the JSON file into the HTML page.

Say you wanted to display a datatable with two fields - names and DOBs - your JSON would look *something like this*:

```
{
  [
    ["John Doe", "5.4.1996"],
    ["Jane Doe", "5.4.2006"]
  ]
}
```

On the HTML page:

```
let response = await fetch(url);

if (response.ok) { // if HTTP-status is 200-299
  // get the response body (the method explained below)
  let json = await response.json();
  // TODO: put the retrieved json into the datable
} else {
  alert("HTTP-Error: " + response.status);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm a bit confused however- so would I first have to convert my CSV to JSON, then use that bit of javascript to fetch the JSON, but where would I actually put it inside the table for the user to see? I can't see in the javascript where it imports the json file itself.

Comment: Yes, first you have to convert the data to JSON. You have to write the bit where you import the JSON into the datatable yourself, but that's easy, just consult the docs for your datatable of choice.

Comment: I am very new to all this so not sure where to even look. I am planning on using a bootstrap 4 table if that helps?

Comment: I don't think Bootstrap(4) ships with a datatable, you're gonna have to use a 3rd party. I personally use ReactTable: https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table

Comment: Oh right okay, what about this? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/

Comment: That's a table, not a datatable (i.e. you can't sort using columns).

Comment: I would not need to be able to sort the data, just search it. Would I be able to use the method above with tables?

Comment: @NinoŠkopac I was able to handle around 80K records with php and datatables, However this process send the data in chunks, and from a personal experience most mayor browsers cant handle more than 90K records, I think 30K is an okay amount of data to handle with HTML, So if the data will be static from a large amount of time use some file as data source otherwise use the database

Comment: Search it with a browser (i.e. CTRL+F)? Then yes, you can use normal tables

Comment: I was planning on using the normal bootstrap filter table. So are you saying that 5000 entries of pure HTML is manageable by a browser?

Comment: Sure. Also, I suggest that in the future you turn more into trial and error and figure things out for yourself - it tends to stick in memory that way.

Comment: No worries- it's my first site, I've learnt a lot doing this but I didn't want to mess this up since it'll take ages to turn this excel document into a bootstrap table. Not sure where to start really. I'm sure there's a way to paginate the bootstrap table

Comment: I hope I was able to point you in the right direction with advice and code samples - please upvote and accept my answer if that's the case.